# NOVICE: Web application using HTML, CSS, AngularJS, NodeJS, MySQL?

Tags: html, mysql, css, angularjs, node.js

I have searched the web endlessly hoping to find a definitive answer but still have not found one.

I am in the beginning stages of trying to write a web application and I want to make sure I am using the right languages before I get too far into it. Right now my plan is this:

```
Front End: HTML, CSS, AngularJS
Back End: NodeJS, MySQL
```

Is this an a good combination? I know everyone has their opinions but will this at least work?

Do I need frameworks like yeoman and/or express for it to work?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Yeoman is not a framework. It is a scaffolding tool.

Comment: Let me know if you need more specific info etc, otherwise please would you consider marking as correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, yes that is a sensible stack - obviously, like everything else, your DB needs will depend on what your app is trying to do etc, but if for a fairly standard web application mysql is good - (mongodb as a nosql db is quite popular with node apps too). Also, consider [Express](http://expressjs.com/) (very popular web server for NodeJS env).

Google for **MEAN stack** (**Mongo, Express, Angular, Node**), and you should find plenty of resources to get started. One such resource for single page app development with MEAN is [here](https://scotch.io/tutorials/setting-up-a-mean-stack-single-page-application)

Of course, in your situation you may wish to swap out Mongo for MySql. There are many good [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/) modules to support your needs. If you wish to consider an MVC framework then consider something like [SailsJS](http://sailsjs.org/). Just google for "best Nodejs MVC frameworks" find other alternatives.

You will also find that the JS community has produced lots of 'starter packs' (usually published on github repos), as well as [yeoman](http://yeoman.io/) generators. For instance, one such generator for a full angular stack is can be found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/generator-angular-fullstack). But please do some research and ensure it is documented and being maintained etc before using one.

Angular 1.x has proven to be a great SPA framework, and is still very relevant. You might also wish to check [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) too, which has gained a lot of popularity over the past year.

Finally, for the **HTML** (styling with **CSS**), consider using [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/), or [material design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html). Bootstrap is overwhelmingly the most popular choice for CSS styling, and you can get more bootstrap themes at sites like [wrap bootstrap](https://wrapbootstrap.com/).

Comment: For my particular app I think I need to use MySQL for the organization I do not think a nosql db will work.   Any recommendations for frameworks etc.?

Comment: Thank you for the response btw

Comment: @EricScandora- since you are just starting out - consider taking a look at SailsJS (link in answer).  This was inspired by Rails and can simplify backend development a great deal. It also uses an ORM called Waterline so very easy to connect with MySql.  Otherwise, check MEAN stack, and just swap out all the mongoDB parts with a MySql and a MySql adapter.

Comment: updated the answer with more links, and some info on css.

Comment: @Sevle - thanks for pointing out broken link. If you found answer helpful, feel free to upvote :)